# Domain of $g(x)=\sqrt{\sin(π\sin(πx))}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let a function
$$g(x)=\sqrt{\sin(π\sin(πx))}$$

If I have want to find its domain.
The first step wil be making the term inside the square root greater than or equal to zero
i.e.
$$\sin(π\sin(πx))   \ge 0$$

Further we can say
$$ 2nπ \le   π\sin(πx)  \le (2n+1)π$$

Where $n \in Z$

$$ 2n \le   \sin(πx)  \le (2n+1)$$

But now I am stuck. Further I think here we will be using inverse trigonometry but I have not been familiar with inequalities involving inverse trigonometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far you made good progress, you are not missing much.

After simplifying the $\pi$ you get
$$2n\leq \sin(\pi x)\leq 2n+1$$
now, knowing that $\sin$ ranges in $[-1,1]$ you only have to consider $n=0$ and the special case $\sin(\pi x)=-1$ (with $n=-1$).

Thus you end up with the case
$$0\leq \sin(\pi x)\leq 1$$
which as before leads to
$$2m\pi\leq \pi x\leq (2m+1)\pi$$
thus
$$2m\leq x\leq (2m+1)$$

and the special case is just $x=-\frac{1}{2}+2m$

This is confirmed by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%7Bsin%28pi*sin%28pi*x%29%29%7D)

Also

[Graph by Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mwkx7ypabf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mathematica to calculate the result.

```
n = 2;
f = Nest[Sin[Pi*#] &, x, n]
Reduce[f >= 0, x, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

$$
c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land (2 x+1=4 c_1\lor 2 x=3+4 c_1\lor 0\leq x-2 c_1\leq 1)
$$